# How to fix app displaying of boxed question mark glyph for certain non-displaying Unicode characters?

Tags: font

In various windows in Anki 2.1, text becomes garbled by the display of a few Unicode characters as question marks in squares. For example:

[image: note browser garbled text]

User dae on the [Anki forums](https://forums.ankiweb.net/t/garbled-character-display/11131) identified the characters as the [First Strong Isolate](https://codepoints.net/U+2068) (U+2068) and [Pop Strong Isolate](https://codepoints.net/U+2069) (U+2069) characters.

### Checking the font

Peering into a running Anki process, the widgets are using the font family ".SF NS Text", the system font. The installed system font (/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSText.ttf) has version 14.0d1e3 (retrieved with FontForge), but unfortunately Apple's list of [Mojave's fonts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208968) doesn't include the versions for system fonts. The "14" is suggestive of Mojave, though [High Sierra includes some fonts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207962) with a major version of 14. The greatest [font version in Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206872) is 12. My installed system font is copyrighted 2015–2017, a period during which Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite, El Capitan, Sierra and High Sierra were active (though only the latter 4 were in support in 2017, and only the latter 2 were the latest version of macOS during 2017).

### Other evidence

Anki is the only application I've noticed this in, but other Anki users have not experienced the issue. Moreover, if I create a new user on my computer and open Anki, it does not display the question-mark-in-a-box glyph.

I recall first seeing the problem in High Sierra, which was a clean install with user data imported from a Time Machine backup. The problem has persisted through updates & reinstalls.

### Attempted solutions

- update/reinstalled Anki
- validated fonts in FontBook (which doesn't include the system font, but...)
- cleared caches with `sudo atsutil databases -remove`
- restored standard fonts with `sudo fontrestore default`
- reinstalled OS X 10.14.6
- removed Anki's preferences (from ~/Library/Preferences) and app data (~/Library/Application Support/Anki)
- renamed fontconfig caches to disable them (~/.cache/fontconfig, ~/.fontconfig, /opt/local/var/cache/fontconfig, /opt/local/var/cache/fontconfig-*.cache*)
- possibly others I've forgotten

### The Question

What other steps can I take to resolve this issue?

### System Info

- OS X 10.13.6–10.14.6
- Anki 2.1.40–2.1.44 (and probably earlier)

Comment: I know nothing about Anki, but just to note that the San Fransisco font family dosen't need to be an 'installed' font [& in fact for the first few years it wasn't available separately for user install at all] It's embedded in the OS itself. I can confirm no Mac here can render those glyphs, [tested El Cap->Big Sur] Windows 10 can't deal with them either. I'd call it an Anki bug.